# Can KIE workbench 6.5.0 connect to remote repository (not localhost)?

Tags: git, kie-workbench

My question is whether it is possible to connect from KIE workbench to a remote repository, like one in github.

From Drools documentation (version 6.5.0):

> When cloning git Repositories it is now possible to use SCP style URLS, for example git@github.com:user/repository.git

I have been searching the internet to find some more information on it, but I still do not know whether it is actually possible to connect to a remote git other than the information I got from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/drools-setup/a1qFlehzJqs/6Ouw-IztCAAJ).
Is it possible to connect from the workbench to a remote repository (i.e. not localhost)? Can you do pull and push requests? Does some tutorial exist?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it can, but I am doing a workaround now with SourceTree connecting to the KIE workbench git located in the server and then doing pulls from inside the workbench and push from outside.

Your URI would be to the repository located in (in my case):
`<installation directory>\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\bin\.niogit\<repositoryName>.git`

For being a workaround it is not exactly an answer to my question, so I will keep the thread open just in case someone is able to provide more information and therefore a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was going back to 6.4 and 6.5 for some reason and got the see how elementary the git was back then.

So you are right, basic operation to external git is possible from Workbench: 
Home --> Administration --> Repositories --> Clone Repository --> Selected Remote Git rep details and respective username/password

From then you continue to work on the local one. There is an option to go from back-end command line to push. From the directory that you have started the Wildfly, there is a .niogit folder containing the git repositories. In everyone of those you can have a finer control.

For pull I guess it is more complicated as after pull re-indexing of the content is needed to be visible in Workbench.

Thank
/Z